# Add .so files to Cordova Plugin

Tags: android, cordova, ionic2, cordova-plugins, cordova-android

I have developed a Cordova Plugin for my Ionic app, which throws the following error when accessed:

> java.lang.UnstatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader
>   [DexPathList [[zip file "/data/app/io.ionic.starter-2/base.apk"],
>   nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/io.ionic.starter-2/lib/arm/,
>   /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]] couldn't find "libserial_port.so"

I've put `libserial_port.so` file in the libs folder, at this path: `pluginName\src\android\libs\armeabi\libserial_port.so`.

Then, in `plugin.xml` I've tried to load it both as a resource file:

`<resource-file src="src/android/libs/armeabi/libserial_port.so" target="src/android/libs"/>`

and as a lib-file:

`<lib-file src="src/android/libs/armeabi/libserial_port.so" />`

However, the error still appears. What shall I do for the app to see that library?

Comment: I am also facing same issue after using Cordova 8 (Cordova-Android 7).Were you able to resolve it ?

Comment: @manjunathkallannavar I'm facing the issue too. Did you able resolve or workaround the issue?

Comment: I am able to resolve the issue .Add .so files in both jniLibs  and lib and delete  either of them based on your cordova version

Answer (score 2):

I am able to resolve this issue by renaming libs to jniLibs.

Change

`<resource-file src="src/android/libs/armeabi/libserial_port.so" target="libs/armeabi/libserial_port.so">`

to

`<resource-file src="src/android/libs/armeabi/libserial_port.so" target="jniLibs/armeabi/libserial_port.so">`

also read my answer with similar issue [Unable to run Android app after updating to cordova android 7.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48853992/unable-to-run-android-app-after-updating-to-cordova-android-7-0-0)