# Unable to run Android app after updating to cordova android 7.0.0

Tags: java, android, cordova, cordova-plugins, cordova-android

I have created an Cordova Android 7 app while running app I get an **error at**

> system.load("xxxx")
>
> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader
>   ......:couldn't find "xxxx.so"

in **plugin.xml** file I have defined **jar** and **.so** file like below :

`<lib-file src="src/android/libs/xxxxx.jar"/>`

`<resource-file src="src/android/libs/armeabi/xxxx.so"   target="libs/armeabi/xxxx.so" />`

I hav tried all the possible ways by changing paths but no luck.What should  be done to load library correctly ?

PS:The app works fine with cordova android version <7.

There is similar SO thread [Add .so files to Cordova Plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48665656/add-so-files-to-cordova-plugin)

Answer (score 1):

I am able to resolve this issue by renaming libs to jniLibs.

Change

`<resource-file src="src/android/libs/armeabi/xxxx.so"
target="libs/armeabi/xxxx.so"/>`

to

`<resource-file src="src/android/libs/armeabi/xxxx.so"
target="jniLibs/armeabi/xxxx.so"/>`